# Phrase meaning of: "A man who maintains."

Tags: phrase-meaning, idioms, phrases, idiomatic-language

Of course I can check a dictionary for the meaning of "maintain" but I don't think the phase "a man who maintains" makes sense as a whole.

The full context:

> ... a man who knows what he wants, what he stands for, what he will and
> won't tolerate. A man who's decisive and resolute. **A man who
> maintains.**

Comment: It doesn't make much sense.  More context needed, in particular we need the source of the quote, and at least a full sentence.

Comment: It's from "Get Women to Respect You" at _[Girls Chase](https://www.girlschase.com/content/respect-relationship-where-it-comes-where-it-goes)_. I _knew_ I'd seen it _somewhere._

Comment: @JamesK It is an article about attractive male.

Comment: The dude abides.

Comment: @Astralbee So you mean it is a man who follow the rules?

Comment: The writing is poor at that site, @High GPA. The meaning is probably made clearer by this repellent sentence a few lines below it: **Respect in a relationship is maintained when male dominance is maintained.**

Comment: @HighGPA No... I think it means someone who is unmoveable, unyielding, stands their ground. I was just dropping a quote from a film because it was structurally similar and equally confusing. In hindsight, it probably wasn't helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Gosh, what a horrible website. There's so much good English written, but this isn't it.

Note that in the quote the word "maintains" is written in italics.  This indicates that this isn't a standard construction in English, and you'll need to use context.  It appears to mean "a man who keeps things steady and doesn't change his mind."  He maintains *things*.

But please.  The whole website is just page after page after page of woman-hating bullshit.  Avoid.

Answer (score 1):

"Maintain" has various traditional uses, all related to *keeping something as it is* or *holding onto* something. As such, it is usually used transitively - for example, "I have a family to maintain", or "he maintains his opinion".

A more modern, intransitive use of the word that matches your example can mean variously to keep one's composure, to be steadfast, or to be unmoveable in whatever the wider context of the statement applies.

['Maintain' by Steve Burns](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s6EFkC7GPkw)